# cycle through carousel slides using keyboard right and left smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 carousel that I want to navigate using keyboard keys. As of now I'm using this code

```JavaScript

```
$('.carousel').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
       $(".carousel").carousel('previous');
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      $(".carousel").carousel('next');
      return false;
    }
  });
```

```
The code works but I have click each slide before navigating to then next using keyboard arrow keys. Something tells me there is something I'm missing. What could it be?

If you need to test the whole code, the carousel repo is at https://github.com/ericwjr/notice. It's also live via github pages